# VBA Find a Row with two variables then time stamp a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

Could anyone give me advice on how to look up a row in a spreadsheet which matches two criteria, then change the data in specific Cells.

The data will be like this..

```
Reference   Version    date1        date2         date3
ABC1        1          11/12/2013
ABC1        2          31/12/2013
ABC2        1          12/12/2013
ABC3        1          12/12/2013
ABC1        3          01/01/2014
```

In VBA I wish to be able to find the row that matches the reference and the version number, then datestamp column 4 of that 1 unique row.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
   Dim refToFind As String
   Dim versToFind As String

   refToFind = "ABC1"
   versToFind = "1"

   'address of first reference
   Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("B2")
   lastrow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - Rng.Row

   For i = 0 To lastrow
       If CStr(Rng.Offset(i, 0).Value) = refToFind _
               And CStr(Rng.Offset(i, 1).Value) = versToFind Then
          Rng.Offset(i, 4) = Now
       End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, really apreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for a position for two criteria can be solved by this array formula (in this sample looking up `ABC3` and `1` in `A2:B6`
[image]

This formula can be used in VBA to provide the position for the timestamp:

*VBA Equivalent*

```
Sub OneWay()
Dim lngRow As Long
lngRow = Evaluate("=MATCH(1,(A2:A6=""ABC3"")*(B2:B6=1),0)")
Cells(lngRow + 1, 4) = Now()
End Sub
```

or just:

```
Sub OneWay2()
lngRow =  Cells(Evaluate("=MATCH(1,(A2:A6=""ABC3"")*(B2:B6=1),0)")+ 1, 4) = Now()  
End Sub
```